# How is the initial price of a cryptocurrency determined?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ico, price, cryptoeconomics

I know how or what affects the price of a mature coin (buying and selling). But when it is first minted, what determines its initial price?

This is not a philosophical question I'm asking. I was actually looking into how to create a new crypto coin/token - I now know the process of how to create a coin/token in a language called Solidity, and also how to write smart contracts on the token we just created. But nowhere in the token creation process I saw anything regarding its initial price. You need to mention the total initial supply, the wallet address of the first holder, etc, but nowhere you need to mention its initial price. And when you create the coin and add it to your wallet, even if you hold all the supply of the token, the value of your coins shows as zero dollars.

So, what determines its initial price? How does the price first become non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't code initial price of coin

You can decide on initial price , you can start with as low as you want or as high as you want

1:) https://youtu.be/cizLhxSKrAc check this video out

You can choose whichever price you want to list if for . But take note of marketcap (number of coins issued multiplied by price of the coin) . Higher the market cap less chance of volatility and less chance it will go to "moon"

People generally prefer lower marketcap coins because the faster it will go to "moon"

Comment: The video you linked was on liquidity pools. I know about these, and understand the concepts of yield farming and impermanent loss and all that. But I don't see how that's related to this question - how is the INITIAL price of a coin determined. Could you please explain its relevance in the context of this question?

Comment: 1) if you are listing in a centralized exchange you can list it as high as you want , after that it will depend on the market whether they want to buy at that price or not . Its not coded into the smart contract price is determined by free market

Comment: 2:) If you are listing in uniswap initially if you are planning to list lets say 5 tokens at the price of 10$ then you first have to create a pool which includes 5 tokens and 50$ in eth(5*10) .. such that initially each token would be worth 10$ and after that it will depend on the market if people want to buy at that price or sell

Comment: theoretically in centralized exchange you can list as high as you want but usually exchanges take into consider various factors like at which price you raised private sale amount or at which price you are trading in other exchanges or at which price you are trading in uniswap like protocols they take into many consideration..

Comment: and btw if you are familiar with ganache and truffle can you please check my issue out

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, if I understand correctly, you create the coin, then you need to go to an exchange and provide the first liquidity to that token. There, you are free to give whatever value you want to your freshly minted coin, by saying how much of it you want to trade for a given known coin, like ETH, or BTC, or BNB, etc. And that creates the initial price. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I am not familiar with ganache and truffle.

Comment: Yes exactly, You have to provide initial liquidity to set the initial price and further market will decide its price after that